# How to hide the vaadin-connection-indicator in Vaadin Flow

Tags: connection, vaadin-flow, indicator

I've recently migrated some projects from Vaadin Flow 14.10.0 to Vaadin Flow 23.2.17.
After the migration I noticed that a vaadin-connection-indicator has appeared on the bottom of the page showing the "Online" connection status. As it would be useless for my users, I was wondering if there was a way to hide this connection indicator, but was not able to find anything about in the Vaadin Flow documentation.

Could anyone help on this?

Many thanks in advance,
Giuseppe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed that a `vaadin-connection-indicator` has appeared on the bottom of the page showing the "Online" connection status.

I find your question odd as `vaadin-connection-indicator` is not appearing on the bottom of the page when visible, but on the top. It is the blue bar that appears when synchronous request takes long to handle. You can hide it by using CSS in your main styles.css file.

```
vaadin-connection-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. You probably don't want to hide whole `vaadin-connection-indicator` (still want to see the progress bar on the top). You just need to hide the status message (the "Online" message at the bottom):

```css
.v-status-message {
   display: none;
}
```